# Does Google use the text property in image object schema markup to determine the relevance of a page to a query?

Tags: google, googlebot, images, schema.org, markup

I'm creating a page that summarizes a variety of statistics on a topic. I believe a dashboard-like graphic like [this one](https://www.unhcr.org/figures-at-a-glance.html) would provide a better experience than a textual list of the statistics.

However, since much of the text will be hidden from GoogleBot in the graphic, it will have less info to judge the relevance of the page to a search query.

The [image object schema](https://schema.org/ImageObject) includes a text property, which schema.org described as "*The textual content of this CreativeWork*".

I'm considering including the text in the image as a text property in the image object schema markup.

**Will GoogleBot consider the content of the text property in the image object schema markup in its judgement of page relevance?**

(To clarify, this question is about Google's opinion of the page, not the image; although I'm curious whether there would be an effect on image search).

Comment: you care about the relevance of the text to the image for image search or just about the relevance of the text to the page for web search?

Comment: @Stephen Ostermiller I had the relevance of the text to the page for web search in mind when I asked the question; although I'm curious whether there would be an effect on image search.

Comment: I don't believe Google has documented any support for schema and image text. Their official support is via the img alt attribute.